# Слово "печеньки"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сейчас в интернете стало очень популярно слово-урод "печеньки". Пытаюсь бороться с этим, но что предложить взамен? Какая уменьшительная форма от слова "печенье"? "Печенюшки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем с ним бороться?  Слово как слово. Фиксируется словарями, правда пока как просторечное.

Уменьшительное - печеньице, но вы, видимо, не о нем спрашиваете.

Всё дело в том, что для печенья нет специального слова, обозначающего *одну штуку печенья*. Как, скажем, макаронина для макароны. Поэтому для печенья приходится употреблять одно и то же слово и для штуки, и как собирательное. Аналогичная ситуация имеет место и для, например, мороженого или пирожного, но это товар всё-таки штучный, в собирательном значении употребляется редко. А печенье обычно фасованная мелочь, другой раз даже на вес продаётся. И возникает естественная потребность сказать "одна штука печенья" нормальным языком. Мне, конечно, печенюшка больше по душе, но вот у неё-то гораздо более выраженный ласкательный характер. Так что с печенькой готов смириться.

Comment: Спасибо за защиту печеньки. А я прочитала вопрос и думаю: "Ну вот еще одна моя ошибка из детства" Потому что у нас так говорят очень давно!Правда, именно в единственном числе: возьми съешь печеньку"

Answer (score 0):

В Ленинграде, а потом и в Петербурге, мы всю жизнь говорили "печенинка". А теперь все там говорят на каком-то "мимимишном" языке: печенька, спасибки (а не спасибо), вкусняшка (а не вкуснятина), мороженка, одеялко, споки ночи (а не спокойной ночи), чмоки, целю (целую) и т. д. В общем, культура речи почти утрачена, появилась какая-то субкультура... Всё можно понять, в шутку можно слова поковеркать, но эти уродцы уже почти стали нормой! Вот так и подтверждается мысль, что язык - это отражение менталитета и жизни людей, на нём говорящих.

Comment: Понять-то все можно, но вот ныть по поводу того, что раньше все хорошо было, - это не к нам. "Печененка" мне, кстати, совсем не по вкусу. При том, что ленинградскую речь знаю хорошо: бывал, слушал, родственников полгорода имел. Мимимишки - это все проходящее,  наши бабушки точно так же недовольны были нашей речью - и было за что. А вот форма для одной штуки печенья - это жизненная необходимость. Она, если устроит, может в языке закрепиться.